# Why did Jesse completely change when Walt gave him his $5 million in season 5?

Tags: character, breaking-bad

Obviously Jesse was disturbed when Todd killed that kid on the bike in *Breaking Bad* season 5. Then he decided to stop cooking and asked Walt for his share of the millions. He wanted the money so that he can live the way he wanted. But the moment he gets the money, he shuts the door, sits down and start crying. After that he goes out and starts throwing the money. I did not get this. What exactly happened when Walt gave him his money?

Comment: Blood money, regret.

Comment: Before this instance also we have seen life's were lost and the reason was  meth even jesse lost his friend Christian "Combo" Ortega but then also he continued with the work and continued earning money but what exactly was serious about this instance.

Comment: Because he saw someone like himself shoot a little boy for no reason. Adults dying just doesnt register the same way

Comment: @DarkArmy he is more attached to kids, it has been displayed various times.

Comment: @DarkArmy Check my updated answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jesse didn't completely change. Jesse was very sensitive from the begining. The shooting of boy, by Todd, definitely had an impact on Jesse. He not only asks Walt for money, but also asks Saul to help him give away his money. When Saul refuses, he starts throwing the money and gets arrested.

[EDIT]

Refering to the OP's comment **what exactly was serious about this instance?**

Earlier incidents also traumatized Jesse to a lesser degree, like the killing of Andrea's brother by drug dealers. But at this point, when Todd killed the boy, maybe he had had enough. Jesse faced several such traumas during the series following which he always recovered, but we can see that he reached the breaking point after this incident. Before this, everything seemed to be fine. Gus was gone, they were doing independent business, Jesse was living with Andrea and Broch, but then this incident occurs and Jesse just seemed to have enough of it. There were a series of incidents, but this one acted as the breaking point.